# How to regex match multiple items

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle

I have a `reviews` table as follows:

| r_id | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Weight cannot exceed 40 kg |
| 2 | You must not make the weight go over 31 k.g |
| 3 | Don't excel above 94kg |
| 4 | Optimal weight is 45 kg |
| 5 | Don't excel above 62 kg |
| 6 | Weight cannot exceed 7000g |

What I want to select is the weight a `r_id`'s cannot exceed. So my desired output is

| r_id | max weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 3 | 94 |
| 5 | 62 |

As you can see, `r_id` 4 wasn't included since it wasn't taking about the maximum weight and `6` wasn't included because it is in grams. I am struggling with two things.

1. There are multiple phrases, how can I do a `OR` operator check in my regex column.
2. Sometimes the `kg` number is written like `40kg`, `40 KG`, `40 k.g` or `40kilos`. While all things are `kilograms`, the `kg` is written in different ways. How can I only extract the number (but ensuring the `kg` is written in one of the above ways, so I don't accidentally extract something like `4000g`.

---

```
SELECT
  r_id,
  REGEX_SUBSTR(REGEX_SUBSTR('cannot exceed [0-9]+ kg'), '[0-9]+ kg')) as "max weight"
FROM reviews;
```

My statement only checks for one particular type of sentence and doesn't check if the number is in kilograms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just extract the number from the string.  There only appears to be one and then check if the string looks like certain patterns:

```
select regexp_substr(comm, '[0-9]+')
from reviews
where regexp_like(comm, '(exceed|go over|above).*[0-9]+ ?(kg|k.g)');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9fa330fb9f4846a5c579859de856931b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: The issue with this approach is what if the sentence is `You should not exceed the weight if your back is hurting` So I was wanting something like `should not exceed <number> <some variation of kg>`

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov . . . You can adapt this to your particular strings.  You are going to have to customize this.  This version works on the question that you asked.

Comment: I have a question in regards to your solution. How did you manage to match `r_id` `4`. There was not a space? it was `94kg`

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov . . . The space is optional because of the `?`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more robust regex expression to extract the number.

I don't have an oracle DB, but try something like:

```
SELECT
  r_id,
  REGEX_SUBSTR(comment, '([0-9]+) ?(k\.?g\.?|kilos)', 1, 1, 'i') as "max weight"
FROM reviews;
```

You can see this regex matching the given string in action at https://regex101.com/r/07Rstk/1. This also explains what the regex means.

We also turn on the case insensitive flag in order to properly handle any capitalization. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/olap.112/e17122/dml_functions_2069.htm

Edit: To do checks for exceed, go over, etc. Note that we have changed the position parameter from 1 to 2 since we now care about the second capture group.

```
SELECT
  r_id,
  REGEX_SUBSTR(comment, '(exceed|go over|above)\h*([0-9]+) ?(k\.?g\.?|kilos)', 1, 2, 'i') as "max weight"
FROM reviews;
```

Comment: This matched on `r_id` `4` which shouldn't have been matched as we have to also check if the sentence has with terms like `cannot exceed`, `go over`, `excel above` before it states the kilogram number